# Escaping variable in script

Tags: terminal, bash

I'm using script.sh in an OS X Mavericks terminal containing only the following:

```
echo ${1}
ls ${1}
```

Now, when I call `./script.sh "/Users/me/some\ directoy\ with\ whitespace/"`, the echo command prints `/Users/me/some\ directoy\ with\ whitespace/`, but `ls` still insists on splitting everything up, so the results there are

```
ls: /Users/me/some\: No such file or directory
ls: directoy\: No such file or directory
ls: with\: No such file or directory
ls: whitespace/: No such file or directory
```

Notice the `\` at the end of the first three error lines. How do I do this correctly?

(I'm aware that using both "" and \ in the input argument leaves the \ in my variable, but I assume I would need those.)

I also tried using `./script.sh /Users/me/some\ directoy\ with\ whitespace/` without the quotes, then making the script

```
echo ${1}
ls "${1}"
```

but that made the `echo` output not contain any `\` now, and the `ls` output looks like this:

```
ls: "/Users/me/some\: No such file or directory
ls: directoy\: No such file or directory
ls: with\: No such file or directory
ls: whitespace/": No such file or directory
```

Notice that all it did was add the quotes without seeming to understand them as syntax.

---

It is somehow related to the [IFS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) (input field separator) since if I make the script

```
IFS=*
ls ${1}
```

and run it as `./script.sh /Users/me/some\ directoy\ with\ whitespace/`, it correctly shows me the content of the specified directory. I'm not sure why, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the braces. This should work just fine:

```
echo $1
ls "$1"
```

You don't want to use backslashes and quotes in the directory name. One or the other should be fine.

Comment: Tried it that way, didn't work either. I suspect something is wonky with my bash, because it works on Ubuntu.

Comment: I just tested in Yosemite and it's fine.

Comment: The above script also works for me. @G.Bach Did you notice mike's comment about not using slashes and quotes at the same time when you call it. Do this command: `./script.sh "/Users/me/some directory with whitespace/"` -- with quotes and no backslashes and in your script use `"$1"` not `"$(1)"`

Comment: I tried that as well, it doesn't work in my OS X, but does in Ubuntu - very strange. Thank you both for trying it out!

Answer (score 1):

The correct script is

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${1}"
ls "${1}"
```

(You can start with `#!/bin/sh` instead if you prefer.)

The syntax of bash and other shells is a bit weird. You might think that `$var` means “the value of `var`”, but it doesn't. It means “take the value of `var`, split it at each whitespace sequence (or more generally, split it according tot he value of `IFS`), and interpret each part as a glob pattern which, if it matches any file, is replaced by the list of matches”. Yes, that's quite a mouthful — which is why you should always write `"$foo"` instead. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions unless you know why you need to leave them out. Inside double quotes, the meaning of `"$foo"` is “the value of the variable `foo`”.

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for further discussion of this topic.

To invoke your script, you can use any form of quoting — but only one:

```
./script.sh /Users/me/some\ directoy\ with\ whitespace/
./script.sh "/Users/me/some directoy with whitespace/"
./script.sh '/Users/me/some directoy with whitespace/'
```

If `./script.sh /Users/me/some\ directoy\ with\ whitespace/` doesn't work with the quotes in the script, then you aren't typing that in a bash shell. I can't guess what else you might be typing it in. Or else you didn't test with the version of the script you thought you had.

Comment: I don't quite remember how I fixed my problem, but I think I tried the script you suggested - without success. I must be on a very strange bash configuration with that OSX since everything works as intended in other OSes. Thanks for the link!